# Android Mobile Application, XML error

Tags: android, android-xml, mobile-application

Inside of the XML sheet of my app, one of my buttons gives this error:

```
 .xml        android:background="@drawable/tryagain" />
Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n)
```

Comment: try recreating the xml after cleaning the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and then save. It's a matter of formatting. This will format it.

and try to clean your project and retry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open layout file
2. Ctrl+Shift+F (Command+Shift+F in MacOSX)
3. Save the layout file and close it.
4. Delete any .out files the builder might have created.
5. Clean project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all format the xml
if that does not work try cleaning the project
if that also does not work simply recreate the xml.